# Why does my Jenkins pipeline report an error when it executes the sh command

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

here is my jenkinsfile

```
node {
   stage('Preparation') { 
    // for display purposes
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], extensions: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', url: 'https://gitee.com/ilikeyuyuan/test_jenkins.git']]])
   }
   //build
   stage('Build') {
        sh "mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean package"
   }
}
```

The exception is : "sh: 1: ilikeyuyuan: not found"

But ilikeyuyuan is my git name,is not a commond.

everything in my jenkins environment is ok,like java,maven.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf2Of.png)

```
this is my directoryTree
```

[image]

now i change my jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
   //构建
   stages {
      stage('Build') {
          steps{
              sh "mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean package"
          }
      }
   }

}
```

but its the same execption: "sh: 1: ilikeyuyuan: not found"

[image]

Comment: Can you add a step printing the environment variables ? (Please cover all tokens and secretes)

Comment: Also it would be useful having a look at the directory tree

Comment: do you mean the variables in jenkins? this is jenkins environment variables:" M2_HOME:/maven/apache-maven-3.8.4  ,PATH+EXTRA:$M2_HOME/bin.",and this is linux's path     /opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin.  git is anto installed by jenkins .there is no git environment in my container.but have java and maven. what do you mean directory tree? thanks for your help dude

Comment: I mean whats inside the working directory once jenkins clones the repository

Comment: check my question

Comment: Mmm it seems that there is nothing useful here, maybe you have a custom mvn script?

Comment: thanks for your help,but i think the most stranger problem is that the system show my gitee name as commond.

Comment: I would rather say that at some point something is trying to use your gitee name as command, it shouldn't be a system issue. I think it is a problem of compability within you OS and the mvn script